# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) in C Program

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Point2D
{
    double x, y;
}Point2D, *PPoint2D;

double distance(PPoint2D a, PPoint2D b)
{
    return sqrt((a->x - b->x) * (a->x - b->x) + (a->y - b->y) * (a->y - b->y));
}

int main()
{
    PPoint2D a, b;
    (a->x) = 3.0;
    (a->y) = 2.0;
    (b->x) = 1.0;
    (b->y) = 1.0;

    printf("%f", distance(a, b));
}
```

I don't know where am I going wrong , I am trying to get the distance between two vertices a(3,2) and b(1,1) . Any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Pointers `a` and `b` are not initialized and are not pointing to anything.

Comment: Tip: turn on your compiler warnings. It should warn you about this.

Comment: I'd suggest to avoid `PPoint2D` and use an explict `Point2D *` instead, when a pointer is needed.

Comment: Please note that even if you have to pass pointers to those structure, due to the signature of function `distance`, you *don't* have to declare `a` and `b` as pointers in `main` (and dynamically allocate the memory needed to store them). Just declare those as `Point2D a = {3.2, 2.0}; ...` and pass their addresses `... distance(&a, &b) ...`.

Comment: Here are the warnings for your code: https://godbolt.org/z/bno4M18WM  (I have told the compiler to treat warnings as errors - and you should too)

Comment: I completely forgot to initialize the pointer variables . Thank you everyone for letting me know where I went wrong .

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct _Point2D
{
    double x, y;
}Point2D, *PPoint2D;

double distance(PPoint2D a, PPoint2D b)
{
    return sqrt((a->x - b->x)*(a->x - b->x) + (a->y - b->y)*(a->y - b->y));
}

int main()
{
    PPoint2D a, b;
    a = (PPoint2D)malloc(sizeof(PPoint2D));
    b = (PPoint2D)malloc(sizeof(PPoint2D));
    (a->x) = 3.0;
    (a->y) = 2.0;
    (b->x) = 1.0;
    (b->y) = 1.0;

    printf("%f", distance(a, b));
}
```

This solves my problem . Thank you everyone .